# Interface NotImplementedExceptions

Tags: c#, interface, setattribute, getattribute, notimplementedexception

In C#, how do I fill out the required values when implementing an interface.

Here is my interface code:

```
public interface IGridViewWithImageAndTextItem
{
    string type { get; set;}
    string thumbnailDisplayText { get; set; }
    string thumbnailImageWebAddress { get; set; }
}
```

When implementing this interface into a class of mine the following code is added:

```
#region IGridViewWithImageAndTextItem implementation
public string type {
    get {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
    set {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
public string thumbnailDisplayText {
    get {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
    set {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
public string thumbnailImageWebAddress {
    get {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
    set {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
#endregion
```

Now that I have implemented the interface, what values do I substitute for the following code occurrences:

```
throw new NotImplementedException ()
```

Do I change the code to be simple `{ get; set; }` values, or does something else need to be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you only need auto properties. So, yes `{get;set;}` is sufficient.

Comment: It *seems* so, but only you know what your program is supposed to do, so only you can answer your question.

Comment: That totally depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: The title is `Interface NotImplementedExceptions`. What's the question related to `NotImplementedExceptions`? The question is in jeopardy of being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can replace them by

```
{ get; set; }
```

so your code will be:

```
public string type { get; set;}
public string thumbnailDisplayText { get; set; }
public string thumbnailImageWebAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought it would be as simple as that.